# How do I run a Postman collection subfolder with Newman

Tags: json, postman, newman

Postman: 5.5.0
Newman: 3.9.0
OS: Windows 10

How am I supposed to use the --folder command in Newman?

I have a Postman Collection Export (v2.1) which I am loading into Newman using:
- newman run "AME.postman_collection.json"
When I run this command, all tests execute as expected (including all sub folders.

However, I would like to run a specific subfolder called "Media". My understanding is that I should run the commandline:
- newman run "AME.postman_collection.json" --folder "Media"

Unfortunately this does not work. Newman simply reports no failure, but also 0 tests. I have also tried numerous other variations of the --folder parameter such as:
- "AME.Media"
- "AME/Media"
- "AME\Media"
- "\Media"
- "/Media"
- "Media/"
- "Media\"
- ".Media"
- And many, many more

Sample data from the Export below:

```
{
    "info": {
        "name": "AME",
        "_postman_id": "023f6868-4c80-8c0f-01b6-78943caa38a6",
        "description": "",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Media",
            "description": "",
            "item": [
                {
                    "name": "showRenderer",
                    "event": [
```

Comment: hi, how is your collection structure ? you have main collection and subfolders ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updgrading to `v3.9.1` (December 8, 2017).

The [changelog](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md) states

> Fixed folder option handling

that there was in error in folder handling which is now fixed. I tried `v3.9.1` with sub folder and it worked for me.